# Why isn't my incremental source generator generating incrementally?

Tags: c#, sourcegenerators

I've taken a stab at writing an incremental source generator; it is generating the correct source code, but it's not doing so incrementally. I feel like it has to be something wrong with my `Initialize` method or my custom return type (`ClassInfo`) not being cache friendly. I've never written an `IEquatable` either, so I really thing it has something to do with that.

**ClassInfo**

```cs
public readonly struct ClassInfo : IEquatable<ClassInfo>
{
   public readonly string? Namespace { get; }
   public readonly string Name { get; }
   public readonly ImmutableArray<IPropertySymbol> PropertyNames { get; }

   public ClassInfo(ITypeSymbol type)
   {
      Namespace = type.ContainingNamespace.IsGlobalNamespace ? null : type.ContainingNamespace.ToDisplayString();
      Name = type.Name;
      PropertyNames = GetPropertyNames(type);
   }

   private static ImmutableArray<IPropertySymbol> GetPropertyNames(ITypeSymbol type)
   {
      return type.GetMembers()
         .Select(m =>
            {
               // Only properties
               if (m is not IPropertySymbol prop || m.DeclaredAccessibility != Accessibility.Public)
                  return null;

               // Without ignore attribute
               if (GenHelper.IsPropsToStringIgnore(m))
                  return null;

               return (IPropertySymbol)m;
               //return SymbolEqualityComparer.Default.Equals(prop.Type, type) ? prop.Name : null;
            })
         .Where(m => m != null)!
         .ToImmutableArray<IPropertySymbol>();
   }

   public override bool Equals(object? obj) => obj is ClassInfo other && Equals(other);

   public bool Equals(ClassInfo other)
   {
      if (ReferenceEquals(null, other))
         return false;
      //if (ReferenceEquals(this, other))
      //   return true;

      return Namespace == other.Namespace
         && Name == other.Name
         && PropertyNames.SequenceEqual(other.PropertyNames); //  <-- Problem Line
   }

   public override int GetHashCode()
   {
      var hashCode = (Namespace != null ? Namespace.GetHashCode() : 0);
      hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ Name.GetHashCode();
      hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ PropertyNames.GetHashCode(); //  <-- Problem Line

      return hashCode;
   }
}
```

**IncrementalGenerator.Initialize**

```cs
public void Initialize(IncrementalGeneratorInitializationContext context)
{
  context.RegisterPostInitializationOutput(ctx =>
  {
     ctx.AddSource("PropsToStringAttribute.g.cs", SourceText.From(AttributeTexts.PropsToStringAttribute, Encoding.UTF8));
     ctx.AddSource("PropToStringAttribute.g.cs", SourceText.From(AttributeTexts.PropToStringAttribute, Encoding.UTF8));
     ctx.AddSource("PropsToStringIgnoreAttribute.g.cs", SourceText.From(AttributeTexts.PropsToStringIgnoreAttribute, Encoding.UTF8));
  });

  
  var classProvider = context.SyntaxProvider
      .CreateSyntaxProvider(
          static (node, _) => node is ClassDeclarationSyntax { AttributeLists.Count: > 0 },
          static (ctx, ct) => GetClassInfoOrNull(ctx, ct)
          )
      .Where(type => type is not null)
      .Collect()
      .SelectMany((classes, _) => classes.Distinct());

  context.RegisterSourceOutput(classProvider, Generate);

}
```

**GetClassInfoOrNull**

```cs
internal static ClassInfo? GetClassInfoOrNull(GeneratorSyntaxContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
  // We know the node is a ClassDeclarationSyntax thanks to IsSyntaxTargetForGeneration
  var classDeclarationSyntax = (ClassDeclarationSyntax)context.Node;

  var type = ModelExtensions.GetDeclaredSymbol(context.SemanticModel, classDeclarationSyntax, cancellationToken) as ITypeSymbol;

  return IsPropsToString(type) ? new ClassInfo(type!) : null;
}
```

**IsPropsToString**

```cs
public static bool IsPropsToString(ISymbol? type)
{
   return type is not null && 
          type.GetAttributes()
              .Any(a => a.AttributeClass is
              {
                 Name: ClassAttributeName,
                 ContainingNamespace:
                 {
                    Name: PTSNamespace,
                    ContainingNamespace.IsGlobalNamespace: true
                 }
              });
}
```

**IsPropsToStringIgnore**

```cs
public static bool IsPropsToStringIgnore(ISymbol type)
{
   return type is not null && 
          type.GetAttributes()
              .Any(a => a.AttributeClass is
              {
                 Name: PropertyIgnoreAttributeName,
                 ContainingNamespace:
                 {
                    Name: PTSNamespace,
                    ContainingNamespace.IsGlobalNamespace: true
                 }
              });
}
```

As a side note, I mostly followed this https://www.thinktecture.com/en/net/roslyn-source-generators-performance/

**Edit 9/2/22**

I have narrowed down the problem to two lines of code noted above in `ClassInfo.Equals` and `ClassInfo.GetHashCode`; the two lines that deal with equating the array of names. I commented out those two lines and started to get incremental code generation. However, I wasn't getting new code generation when properties changes (as espected), I instead had to change the name of the class(es) to get new code generated (again, as expected).

**Edit 9/7/22**
Added project to [GitHub](https://github.com/ruko1981/PropToString.git)

**Edit 9/8/22**
I tried not using `SequenceEquals` to compare my `PropertyNames` array, but it didnt work.

```cs
public bool Equals(ClassInfo other)
{
   if (PropertyNames.Count() != other.PropertyNames.Count())
      return false;
      
   int i = 0;
   bool propIsEqual = true;

   while (propIsEqual && i < PropertyNames.Count())
   {
      propIsEqual &= SymbolEqualityComparer.Default.Equals(PropertyNames[i], other.PropertyNames[i]);
      i++;
   }

   return Namespace == other.Namespace
      && Name == other.Name
      && propIsEqual;
      //PropertyNames.SequenceEqual(other.PropertyNames); //  <-- Problem Line
}
```

Comment: Just an FYI. It might take me a day to respond to and questions/comments/concerns because of my sh** work schedule. Thank you in advance for any help you may provide!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: If you want to debug a source generator, just add `if (!Debugger.IsAttached) Debugger.Launch();` to the beginning of your generator code and debug the generator process from Visual Studio 2022.

Comment: Please add your code to the question itself, not on an external site.

Comment: I don't see this project on github (I see only Button_IsEnabled_Issue). Is the repo public?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes It is now. Sorry, that was my bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declared `ClassInfo` as struct, so it makes no sense to use `ReferenceEquals` in your `Equals` implementation. It will box the struct and always return other references.

```cs
public bool Equals(ClassInfo other)
{
    return Namespace == other.Namespace
        && Name == other.Name
        && PropertyNames.SequenceEqual(other.PropertyNames);
}
```

`PropertyNames.GetHashCode()` only gets the hash code of the array object but does not include the array items; however it should, as `Equals` does it by calling `SequenceEqual`. The explicit `IStructuralEquatable` implementation of `GetHashCode` in `ImmutableArray<T>` does what we need.

```cs
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    unchecked {
        int hashCode = Namespace != null ? Namespace.GetHashCode() : 0;
        hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ Name.GetHashCode();
        hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^
            ((IStructuralEquatable)PropertyNames)
               .GetHashCode(EqualityComparer<IPropertySymbol>.Default);
        return hashCode;
    }
}
```

The `IPropertySymbol` implementation(s) must override the `Equals` and the `GetHashCode` methods as well. This is also important for `SequenceEqual` to work as expected.

**Edit 22/09/08**

We can remove uncertainties about mysterious equality comparers by comparing the properties ourselves:

```cs
public bool Equals(ClassInfo other)
{
    // Length is faster than the extension method Count()
    if (PropertyNames.Length != other.PropertyNames.Length) {
        return false;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < PropertyNames.Length; i++) {
        if (PropertyNames[i].Name != other.PropertyNames[i].Name) {
            return false; // We don't need to do the other tests.
        }
    }

    return Namespace == other.Namespace && Name == other.Name;
}
```

Note: In your test project the "Counter = x" now gets incremented when we change a property name, but not if we add e.g. a comment.

Consequently, we do the same for `GetHashCode` (see also [What is the best algorithm for overriding GetHashCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/263416/880990) and especially Jon Skeet's answer):

```cs
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    unchecked {
        int hash = 17;
        hash = hash * 23 + (Namespace ?? "").GetHashCode();
        hash = hash * 23 + Name.GetHashCode();
        foreach (IPropertySymbol property in PropertyNames) {
            hash = hash * 23 + property.Name.GetHashCode();
        }

        return hash;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I made the changes you suggested and understand them, but don't know what to do with the last statement. The changes to ```Equals``` and ```GetHashCode``` alone did not fix the issue. Also, in case you want/need to see more code, I posted my project to github (link in question).

Comment: `PropertyNames` is of type `ImmutableArray<IPropertySymbol>`. So, the items in this array must override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` to make `PropertyNames.SequenceEqual(other.PropertyNames)` and my `GetHashCode` work.

Comment: But the items in ```PropertyNames``` are members of a ```TypeSymbol``` objects being passed to the ```ClassInfo``` constructor by a ```SyntaxProvider```.  How do I override ```Equals``` and ```GetHashCode``` for that? Do I make an extension class for ```IProbertySymbol``` and override them in there, or make a custom class that inherits from ```IPropertySymbol``` and override in there, or is there something else?

Comment: Some research tell me that the [IPropertySymbol Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.ipropertysymbol?view=roslyn-dotnet-4.3.0) implements `IEquatable<ISymbol>`. So, these symbols should be okay.

Comment: I looked at the definition of ```ISymbol``` in VS and say that it implements ```IEquatable<ISymbol?>``` so I assumed that I wouldn't need to do it myself. Thats why I was confused by the last statement in your answer. That being said, your answer doesn't fix my problem. Is there something else I should be using besides ```SequenceEqual```? Or maybe I should just loop through ```PropertyNames``` and do the equality check myself?

Comment: I tried manually comparing each element of ```PropertyNames```, but that didn't work either. I added that code as an edit to the question.

Comment: Now, I am comparing the property names explicitly and it seems to work as expected.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that to and got a successful result, but the the name isn't the only thing I want to generate on. What I have in the ```Generate``` method is just something simple I ht

Comment: What I have in the ```Generate``` method is just something simple that I put together to test if the generation was working; not the final version of my generation code. I figured having an array of ```IPropertySymbol```s was better than pulling all the individual pieces I need in the transform stage. I am trying to keep ```ClassInfo``` construction as simple as possible inorder to keep the ```SyntaxProvider``` creation as fast as possible.

Comment: It seems that the [SymbolEqualityComparer](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/3e39dd3535962bf9e30bd650e4ff34b610b8349a/src/Compilers/CSharp/Portable/Symbols/SymbolEqualityComparer.cs#L48) just uses reference equality (not sure, so). So, different compilation passes might return different references for the same symbols.

Comment: You can also compare `prop.Type.Name` and `prop.DeclaredAccessibility` for instance.

Comment: Ok, so, then I can't just do a general comparison of the properties. I'll have to figure something else out, because I wanted to have a property attribute that has parameters to alter what code is generated for each property.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to work through this with me.